# mongoose findByIdAndDelete / findOneAndRemove not deleting

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Im using a basic forms to create/delete info from mongodb.
I can create the records fine enough when i submit the form but when i try to remove a record i keep getting this error:

```
     Cast to ObjectId failed for value " 596f5d7770f6f0d0c2767d3f" at 
path "_id" for model "dwb_notes"
```

I've looked around and most of the answers i see here on SO speak to multiple instances of the app running or multiple programs running on the same port etc, and other varied solutions that aren't directly related to my problem(i think) but i've tried them anyways to no avail.

I only have one record in the db right now for testing. Here is my model:

```
function todoNotesModel(){
    const mongoose = require("mongoose");
    const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

    const NotesSchema = new Schema({
        todoCompany : String,
        todoIsFor : String, 
        todoPostedBy : String,
        todoCompleted : Boolean,
        todoPriority : String,
        todoMessages : Array,
        todoTitle : String,    
        todoDate : String
    });

    const NotesModel = mongoose.model("dwb_notes", NotesSchema);

    return NotesModel;
}

module.exports = todoNotesModel();
```

Using another html form, on load, the delete button is assigned the document id *(in this case its 596f5d7770f6f0d0c2767d3f )*, and appends it to the delete button.
on submit, this id is passed to the delete route via:

```
app.delete("/notesapi/:tabID", (request, response) => {
    NotesModel.findByIdAndRemove(request.params.tabID, (error, data)=>{
        if(error){
            console.log("error in deleting yo!");
            throw error;
        } else {
            console.log("data all gone and deleted yo");
            response.status(204);

        }
    });
});
```

when i run a : `db.dwb_notes.find().pretty()`

i get back :

```
"_id" : ObjectId("596f5d7770f6f0d0c2767d3f"),
"todoCompany" : "",
"todoIsFor" : "",
"todoPostedBy" : "LOGGED IN USER HERE",
"todoCompleted" : false,
"todoPriority" : "green",
"todoTitle" : "",
"todoDate" : "Wed Jul 19 2017 09:23:56 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)",
"todoMessages" : [
        ""
],
"__v" : 0
```

which shows its there so i don't understand why i'm getting this error.
Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried to truncate the ObjectID string? In your error looks like there's a space in your ObjectID string.

Comment: Howdy Zander, what do you mean "truncate"?

Comment: Sorry I meant, stip: http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php

Comment: ahh ok, im on JS but i get it. Let me try it

Comment: oh sorry haha, I was answering PHP questions, got a little caught up. I believe JS has: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim .. `String.trim()`

Comment: OMG IT WORKED!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! you did it THANK YOU. man i been on this for TOO long. You were right. i removed all the code and simply directly added the id number to a dummy var, and it worked. I then took your thory and applied replace(" ", "") and it worked!!! THANK YOU. And yep, just used .trim. Put in full response so i can accept

Comment: haha no problem :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it looks like your error is printing out an additional space in your MongoID String. Creating an invalid MongoID String.

You can use: `string.trim()` [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim)

To remove any spaces before or after the string.

Comment: Thanks this was really helpful. Something so small. Zander, maybe you can help me out with this other issue ive been having that i cant figure out located here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45130054/ajax-network-error-even-though-it-passes-the-information