# findByIdAndDelete not finding the provided id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to use Mongoose `findByIdAndDelete()` method on a model but it does not see the `_id` it needs to delete.

My route is declared similar to this (minified) example:

```
router.delete('/delete-entity/:id', (req, res) => {
  Entity.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id)
    .exec()
    .then((docs) => { ...handle success })
    .catch((err) => { ...handle error });
});
```

I only have middleware running that hooks into the save method of the model. But this middleware does not touch the `_id` field.

When I `console.log()` inside the route I can see that `req.params.id` is set. Also if I try to identify my document using an other field to delete it (so not the `_id` field), it does works. However when I try to use the `_id` field all that is returned to the client is `''`. This makes me believe that something goes wrong in comparing datatypes of the _id field. But cating using `mongoose.Type.ObjectId(`) did not help either.

What could be going on here?

In addition to this already provided information. Here is my model.

```
const embeddedEntity = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true }
}, { _id: false });
const entity = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  embeddedInfo: { type: embeddedEntity, required: true }
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Entity', entity);
```

@Invider I managed to get this from the profiler.

```
{
        "op" : "command",
        "ns" : "development.entities",
        "command" : {
                "findAndModify" : "entities",
                "query" : {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5dc95b8cc472d31232dba5a3")
                },
                "new" : false,
                "remove" : true,
                "upsert" : false,
                "lsid" : {
                        "id" : UUID("30086660-0619-440e-9268-148957428a2b")
                },
                "$db" : "development"
        },
        "keysExamined" : 0,
        "docsExamined" : 0,
        "ndeleted" : 0,
        "numYield" : 0,
        "locks" : {
                "Global" : {
                        "acquireCount" : {
                                "r" : NumberLong(1),
                                "w" : NumberLong(1)
                        }
                },
                "Database" : {
                        "acquireCount" : {
                                "w" : NumberLong(1)
                        }
                },
                "Collection" : {
                        "acquireCount" : {
                                "w" : NumberLong(1)
                        }
                }
        },
        "responseLength" : 74,
        "protocol" : "op_msg",
        "millis" : 0,
        "planSummary" : "IDHACK",
        "execStats" : {
                "stage" : "DELETE",
                "nReturned" : 0,
                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
                "works" : 1,
                "advanced" : 0,
                "needTime" : 0,
                "needYield" : 0,
                "saveState" : 0,
                "restoreState" : 0,
                "isEOF" : 1,
                "invalidates" : 0,
                "nWouldDelete" : 0,
                "nInvalidateSkips" : 0,
                "inputStage" : {
                        "stage" : "IDHACK",
                        "nReturned" : 0,
                        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
                        "works" : 1,
                        "advanced" : 0,
                        "needTime" : 0,
                        "needYield" : 0,
                        "saveState" : 0,
                        "restoreState" : 0,
                        "isEOF" : 1,
                        "invalidates" : 0,
                        "keysExamined" : 0,
                        "docsExamined" : 0
                }
        },
        "ts" : ISODate("2019-11-14T09:27:52.988Z"),
        "client" : "127.0.0.1",
        "allUsers" : [ ],
        "user" : ""
}
```

Comment: [A similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45193379/mongoose-findbyidanddelete-findoneandremove-not-deleting), does it help?

Comment: @invider thanks for your reply. I already came across that post. Unfortunately it did not help me. Besides that I am not getting an error I also tried to trim req.params.id but that did not not gave any different results.

Comment: Check query run by mongo when you call this route. You can run following commands in mongo console after calling your route to get it. 1. `db.setProfilingLevel(2); ` 2. `db.system.profile.find({ns: "mydb.myCollection"}).sort({createdAt: -1}).limit(1).pretty()`

Comment: Can you add your Entity model to the question?

Comment: @SuleymanSah I added it. I now am wondering if it could be the result of setting the _id field to false in the embeddedEntity. Could this effect the parent model?

Comment: I don't think so, but it worths trying :)

Comment: Are you sure you are sending an existing id in the req.params.id?

Comment: @SuleymanSah yes. I can see it if I retrieve all stored Entities in the database.

Comment: To be sure can you create a get router with this code: 
`router.get("/delete-entity/:id", (req, res) => {
  Entity.findById(req.params.id)
    .exec()
    .then(doc = res.send(doc))
    .catch(err => res.status(500).send(err));
});`

Comment: @SuleymanSah finding by the _id does not work either. While I can find the correct document by any other attribute. The problem seems to lie in the use of the _id for some reason.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202319/discussion-between-suleymansah-and-ruud-verhoef).

Comment: @invider I just tried to do as you asked but this just jumped to a new blank line in my cmd after starting the mongo command line. Most likely that has to do with my inexperience using mongo from the command line.

Comment: @invider managed to get the info.

Comment: `ndeleted` value is 0. The query was executed but it did not delete anything. Can you check if you have this document in database with `"_id" : ObjectId("5dc95b8cc472d31232dba5a3")`. Run query `db.entities.find({"_id" : ObjectId("5dc95b8cc472d31232dba5a3")})`

Comment: @invider thanks a lot I managed to locate the issue thanks to your and advise and directions.

Comment: @SuleymanSah a big thanks to you as well as your questions helped me look into the right direction as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot of thanks goes out to @invider and @SuleymanSah for pointing me into the right direction.

The problem was actually something pretty simple that I completely overlooked and was indeed related to the datatype as I expected.

My e2e tests were failing because of the same problem as trying to call the route using Postman.

The problem was that when adding test samples to the database I was setting the `_id` field myself. This most likely causes the value stored to be of type `string`. Letting MongoDB itself set the `_id` field solved this issue. At least for working in the live environment using Postman.

For my e2e test I had to modify my the data that will be loaded into the database for each test. I was adding samples in the following way:

```
{
  _id: '5dc95b8cc472d31232dba5a5',
  name: 'SomeData',
  embeddedInfo: {
    name: 'someOtherData'
  }
}
```

I should have casted the `_id` into an ObjectId first. Like so:

```
{
  _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId('5dc95b8cc472d31232dba5a5'),
  name: 'SomeData',
  embeddedInfo: {
    name: 'someOtherData'
  }
}
```

Again. Thanks to the both of you.

Comment: Glad you made it